# How to query a request at Nodejs Proxy Server?

Tags: node.js, proxy

I have a Nodejs Proxy server like this:

```
`var http = require('http'),
httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

proxy.on('proxyReq', function(proxyReq, req, res, options) {
  proxyReq.setHeader('X-Special-Proxy-Header', 'foobar');
});

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
  proxy.web(req, res, {
    target: 'http://localhost:3000'
  });
 });

console.log("listening on port 9000")
server.listen(9000);`
```

What i want is get the req.body at the proxy server when i post a request to the Origin server, go through the proxy server. 
I used "console.log(req.body);" at both proxy server and the origin server. I get the body object {"id": "user003"} at origin server, but undefined at the proxy server.
So how can i get the req.body at proxy server?

Comment: Where have you defined the variable `proxy`?. Shouldn't it be something like `var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});`

Comment: yes, i have updated it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem here is that you don't have a body parser on your proxy server, but do have one on your origin.

req.body itself isn't set by node. Instead, you have to handle events emitted by the req stream:

```
let body = '';
req.on('data', (data) => {
    // data is a buffer so need toString()
    body += data.toString();
});

req.on('end', () => {
    // at this point you'll have the full body
    console.log(body);
});
```

You can make this easier with a body parser (e.g https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) but since you're running a proxy server, you probably don't want to parse the entire req stream before forwarding onto your origin. So I'd maybe stick with handling the events.

Comment: Yes, i don't have a body parser on the proxy server. Your code work pretty well, and yes, i think it should be handling event instead of using body parser. I just have only one question. The handling event return a string: "id=user003", how to make it an Json object?

Comment: Once you have the entire body (if it was sent as json), call JSON.parse(body)